# how to send an uploaded attachment file to my mailbox from a sign up page

Tags: php, attachment

here is my code am using to send other data but the file attachments doesn't include, the name of the attached file does but there is no file on it the sent mail in my mailbox.

the code:

```
<?

if (empty($_POST)) {
print "Error with form, please contact Customer Service.";
} else {

// Configuration Settings
$SendFrom = "User Registering Info <wilsondaivd@mydomain.com>";
$SendTo = "wilsondaivd@mydomain.com";
$SubjectLine = "New User";
$ThanksURL = "/welcome_process.html"; //confirmation page
$Divider = "~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~";

// Build Message Body from Web Form Input
$MsgBody = @gethostbyaddr($REMOTE_ADDR) . "\n$Divider\n";
foreach ($_POST as $Field=>$Value)
$MsgBody .= "$Field: $Value\n";
$MsgBody .= $Divider . "\n" . $HTTP_USER_AGENT . "\n";
$MsgBody = htmlspecialchars($MsgBody); //make content safe

// Send E-Mail and Direct Browser to Confirmation Page

mail($SendTo, $SubjectLine, $MsgBody, "From: " . $SendFrom);
header("Location: /welcome_process.html");
}

?>
```

what can i add to have the form also mail to me with the attachment? any help will be appreciated.
THANKS

Comment: see an example http://www.finalwebsites.com/forums/topic/php-e-mail-attachment-script

Comment: thanks but this is not doing anything is not sending the users infos and the attachment